# In ExtJS 5: How to remove border of textfield

Tags: extjs, border, textfield, extjs5

In ExtJS 5, I wanna remove border of textfield and make it like this:
[image]

Of course it can be done by two labels, but it's not very clean. I tried following two ways on ExtJS5 official website, but it doesn't work:

```
Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
title: 'Contact Info',
width: 300,
bodyPadding: 10,
renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
items: [{
    // here 1
    xtype: 'textfield',
    name: 'name',
    fieldLabel: 'Name',
    border: 0,    // set border = 0 or false
    hideBorders: true
}, {
    // here 2
    xtype: 'textfield',
    name: 'email',
    fieldLabel: 'Email Address',
    style: 'border: none;background-image:none;'   // set style border none
}]
```

});

Results: 
[image]

Anybody who have any idea? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with displayfiled in place of textfiled
for reference go through the link. http://www.objis.com/formationextjs/lib/extjs-4.0.0/docs/api/Ext.form.field.Display.html

Comment: Thanks Prakash! I didn't know this displayfield before.

Comment: Hi Prakash, just one more thing, how to set its label bold, I tried to add   labelStyle: 'font-weight:bold;'   , but doesn't work. Do you know it?

Comment: try to put the label in bold tag like<b>Name</b>

Answer (score 5):

If you absolutely need to use the textfield xtype, you can remove the border by clearing the [inputWrapCls](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0/5.0.0-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Text-cfg-inputWrapCls) config.  Some Ext JS themes add a border to the div wrapping the input element (and any trigger buttons), so you may have to clear the [triggerWrapCls](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0.0/api/Ext.form.field.Text.html#cfg-triggerWrapCls) config as well.

You will likely also want to modify the [fieldStyle](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0/5.0.0-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Text-cfg-fieldStyle) config to remove the input element's background:

```
{
    xtype: 'textfield',
    name: 'name',
    fieldLabel: 'Name',
    // remove default styling for element wrapping the input element
    inputWrapCls: '',
    // remove default styling for div wrapping the input element and trigger button(s)
    triggerWrapCls: '',
    // remove the input element's background
    fieldStyle: 'background:none'
}
```